# How to Upload Photos on facebook using Graph API in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-4.2

I have made one application, In my application I have integrate Facebook for sharing information.
for Facebook integration I have use Graph API in application.
now In my application, I want to upload photo on user's wall.
I have use this code for upload photo on user's wall.

// for upload photo

```
- (void)uploadPhoto:(id)sender {


NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Image1" ofType:@"jpg"];

NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I think this is a Great Image!"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addFile:filePath forKey:@"file"];
[request setPostValue:message forKey:@"message"];
[request setPostValue:_accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(sendToPhotosFinished:)];
[request setDelegate:self];

[request startAsynchronous];
}
- (void)sendToPhotosFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

// Use when fetching text data
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];
NSString *photoId = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@"Photo id is: %@", photoId);

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"https://graph.facebook.com/%@?access_token=%@", photoId, 
                       [_accessToken stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
ASIHTTPRequest *newRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[newRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(getFacebookPhotoFinished:)];

[newRequest setDelegate:self];
[newRequest startAsynchronous];
}
```

But, here I get
responseString is **{"error":{"message":"Error validating application.","type":"OAuthException"}}** and 
 **Photo id is: (null)**

and Image is not upload on user's wall.
so, please tell me how to solve it.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you must authorize facebook in order to get a valid access token. Are you using the iOS facebook SDK? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ios/

Comment: I also has the same problem has u solved this? If yes can u please tell the reason for this error.

Answer (score 1):

First have you authorized your application to upload pictures by doing this (using the FBConnect SDK), you can checkout all permissions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

```
NSArray* permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"user_photos", nil];
[facebook authorize:permissions];
```

The next problem is that facebook does not allow posts sent in this way to link to pictures hosted on their domains (I know it's REALLY annoying, maybe it would be worth checking if things have changed since april). I spent quite a bit of time working this one out. The way I cracked it was to create a redirect URL using [bitly](https://bitly.com/) (you can access their services programatically using their API, there's an obj-c wrapper for it [here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/bit-ly-wrapper-objective-c-iphone/), although I changed it to be asynchronous) and send that URL in the post.

Answer (score 1):

may help u

```
 //facebook post a image on wall
     NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       userImgView.image, @"picture",
                                       nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                     andParams:params
                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                   andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: facebook is what kind of data type

Answer (score 1):

another way is bellow for post image on Facebook ...

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];

    //create a UIImage (you could use the picture album or camera too)

    UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageNamed:"yourImageName"];
    //create a FbGraphFile object insance and set the picture we wish to publish on it
    FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:picture];

    //finally, set the FbGraphFileobject onto our variables dictionary....
    [variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];

    [variables setObject:@"write your Message Here" forKey:@"message"];

    //the fbGraph object is smart enough to recognize the binary image data inside the FbGraphFile
    //object and treat that is such.....
    //FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"117795728310/photos" withPostVars:variables];
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/photos" withPostVars:variables];
```

hope , this help you...
:)

Answer (score 0):

The facebook API uses OAuth to authenticate requests. You will need to use a library that can request the appropriate temporary/client tokens, and generate the appropriate HTTP headers for requests. This is quite a complicated procedure which involves hashing and normalizing of request arguments.

You cannot do this crafting your own manual HTTP requests .

Answer (score 0):

You can use facebook's native function

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(postImage, 1.0), @"source", self.postTextView.text, @"message", nil];
            /* make the API call */

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) 
{

       if (error == nil) {
               NSLog("Success");
       }
       else {
               NSLog("Failed");
       }

}];
```

Using this code you can post image with message.
Best regards